# Django throws error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: python, django, wsgi, render-to-response

When I run the django server and load the index page it says ...

Error:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'push'.
```

This is my code

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "anything can b written here"}
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the request when return .. It's should be

```
return render_to_response('rango/index.html',context_dict)
```

or use render instead

```
return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

Note:

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: Thanks rajasimon.It worked.I can't vote your answer as I'm running sort of reputations.:-)

Comment: @user2728494 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.